# How to run a procedure once and two procedures 100 times with BehaviorSpace

Tags: netlogo

I would like that BehaviorSpace runs my model 100 times. In my model, I created three buttons :

- the 1st button creates a landscape (procedure "create-landscape")
- the 2nd button initializes turtles (procedure "setup-simulation" in the figure below)
- and the 3rd button runs the model (procedure "start-simulation" in the figure below)

I would like that the 1st button is used once during the 1st simulation in order to keep the same landscape during the 100 simulations (procedures "setup-simulation" and "start-simulation" runs 100 times). How can I do that from "Experiment" (see figure below) ?

Thanks very much for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the reason you're asking this is that you have randomness involved in your landscape generation, such that you get a different landscape each time you run `create-landscape`.

If you want to get the same landscape each time, you could use a fixed [`random-seed`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random-seed) for the landscape generation.

For example:

```
random-seed 0
create-landscape
```

...would always generate the same landscape.

But since you want the rest of your simulation to behave differently from run to run, you can't just use a fixed random seed for the whole thing.

One way to get a fixed seed for the landscape and a varying seed for the rest of the simulation is to use [`with-local-randomness`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#with-local-randomness) for the landscape generation.

Imagine you have an input widget for a `random-seed-for-landscape` global variable. You can create your landscape from your `setup-simulation` procedure like this:

```
to setup-simulation
  with-local-randomness [
    random-seed random-seed-for-landscape
    create-landscape
  ]
  ; rest of your setup procedure...  
end
```

Then even if you ask BehaviorSpace for 100 repetitions, you will always get the same landscape.

And if you would like to experiment with different landscapes, you could put:

```
["random-seed-for-landscape" 0 1 2]
```

In the "Vary variables as follow" section of your BehaviorSpace dialog and run 100 repetitions for each of these three landscapes.

To get a better understanding of the way NetLogo deals with randomness in general, I suggest reading the [Random numbers topic in the programming guide](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#random).